# Nginx returns 502 if service not ready on start

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, ffserver

I'm working on a webcam I built with a Raspberry Pi. It has these components:

- Node.js on port 3000
- FFmpeg / FFserver on port 8090
- Nginx in front to proxy these services together over ports 80/443 (HTTP/HTTPS)

The problem that I am having is that if FFserver is not fully ready on port 8090 when Nginx starts up it will continually return a 502 for `stream.mjpeg`, even though the stream is running. It's as if Nginx determines that the host does not exist and then never tries again. Once I restart/reload the Nginx config it starts working again.

Why does this happen? Is there a retry condition I am missing?

Here is the config for Nginx:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;

    # Basic auth
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
  }

  location /stream.mjpeg {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/stream.mjpeg;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;

    # Basic auth
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
  }
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be happening if there is indeed an application serving on 8090. Have you confirmed that your application is running? What about firewall issues? Is anything listening on 8090? (eg `netstat -atun | grep 8090` might give some indication). As a side note: You don't need to attach `/stream.mjpeg` to your `proxy_pass`. NGINX does this for you because it fell in that location block.

Comment: I can confirm that the service is running by going to that port directly. They do need to be separate locations because they are on different ports. I believe I solved it, however, so see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing the Nginx logs at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I could see that the requests were going to the IPv6 loopback address and not the IPv4. I changed `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` and the issues were resolved. It's still a mystery to me as to why this would work after restarting Nginx but not before.

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;

    # Basic auth
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd;
  }
```

Comment: Nicely solved. Never seen that issue before, thanks!